# How to show files already stored on server with Dropzone in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, dropzone.js, emit

I use this directive to render `Dropzone.js` in page:

```
angular.module('dropzone', []).directive('dropzone', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var config, dropzone;

    config = scope[attrs.dropzone];

    // create a Dropzone for the element with the given options
    dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config.options);

    // bind the given event handlers
    angular.forEach(config.eventHandlers, function (handler, event) {
      dropzone.on(event, handler);
    });
  };
});
```

and in my controller use this code:

```
angular.module('app', ['dropzone']);

angular.module('app').controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dropzoneConfig = {
    'options': { // passed into the Dropzone constructor
      'url': 'upload.php'
    },
    'eventHandlers': {
      'sending': function (file, xhr, formData) {
      },
      'success': function (file, response) {
      }
    }
  };
});
```

In Dropzone to show files already stored on server use `mockFile` and `this.emit` for this. Now how to get `this` and run `emit` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved problem with this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('dropzone', []).directive('dropzone', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var init = function () {
                var config, dropzone;

                config = scope[attrs.dropzone];

                // create a Dropzone for the element with the given options
                dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config.options);


                // Display existing files on server
                if(ngModel.$viewValue !=='' && ngModel.$viewValue !==undefined){
                    var mockFile = {name: ngModel.$viewValue, size: 1234};
                    dropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                    dropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, "uploads/" + ngModel.$viewValue);
                    dropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
                }

                // Form submit rest dropzone event handler
                scope.$on('dropzone.removeallfile', function() {
                    dropzone.removeAllFiles();
                });


                // bind the given event handlers
                angular.forEach(config.eventHandlers, function (handler, event) {
                    dropzone.on(event, handler);
                });
            };
            $timeout(init, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.dropzoneConfig = {
        options: { // passed into the Dropzone constructor
            url: '/api/uploadimage',
            paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: .5, // MB
            acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',
            maxFiles: 1,
        },
        'eventHandlers': {
            'removedfile': function (file,response) {
                $http({
                    method : "POST",
                    url : "/api/uploadimage/"+$scope.customer.avatar_url
                }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                    $scope.deleteMessage = response.data;
                    $scope.customer.avatar_url='';
                });
            },
            'success': function (file, response) {
                $scope.customer.avatar_url = response.filename;
            }
        }
    };
```

and in your Html:

```
<div ng-if="customer.avatar_url!==undefined" ng-model="customer.avatar_url" dropzone="dropzoneConfig" class="dropzone"></div>
```